# Could "closed" questions not be presented on the home page?

Tags: feature-request

If questions are closed, what purpose does it serve for them to be floating on the homepage.  It clutters and takes space away from truly active posts.  It draws attention to an irregularity.  It is not inviting to have a discard pile greet folks.  It just is not tidy or professional for visitors to come upon.  It may be an embarassment to the questioner & even the community.

Answer (score 3):

The home page already has a system of hiding posts that are less useful. Posts with more than a few (5?) downvotes will not show on the home page. This protects the main entry point of the site from sending people to junk content. On a small site like this however, we aren't pushing enough voting weight for this to kick in. I often see it happen on C.SE where really egregious content will get 5 downvotes before it collects 5 close votes, although the latter usually follows soon enough. This is enough to get it off new visitors radar, even though it still shows in the questions page when sorted by "newest".

On a low traffic site like BH, I don't think hiding closed questions would be a good idea. **Quite often, our closed questions can be edited and re-opened. Getting eyes on them is an essential part of this.** Until the right person sees it and figures out a direction to take it, it will just sit there. The faster they get attention and edits the better. If there isn't a way to salvage them, they should be collecting delete (well meaning and written but not on topic) and/or down (lack of research, argumentative, etc) votes.

Comment: That's a good point; I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting point and well put, but on balance I'm in favour of the current system.

The reason I'm in favour of leaving them visible is that when there is something wrong with a question, whether it is a duplicate, off-topic or even poor quality, it is beneficial to see that **as long as the issue is clearly apparent**. This is part of the way we learn how to post, and understand the line around our topic for example. We have no reason to be embarrassed, as the message is not "we have problems here" so much as **"we deal with problems here"**!

Comment: Thank you; that is a helpful perspective.